# Optimization of the work with the database

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, optimization

There is a big enough database of goods that steadily increases.  There are more then 10 millions of goods in the DB now.

There’s a good and there’s its category. Each good has the following attributes: name, price,  amount of sold goods, flags of guarantees and quality etc. There are characteristics of products that are specific only to a particular category. Properties of the goods have the next format - 2000:10000 (the category of the property: the value of the property). Some categories of properties and the properties themselves may overlap in various categories, such as a brand. Filtering, sorting and search for the title and the property is carried out by these categories and properties. The product can be linked to one or more categories.

At first we used only mysql and stored the goods by creating of a table for each category. In this way we had about 6-7 thousand of tables with goods. While selecting we made requests to each of them merging the requests with the help of the operator UNION. With an increase of the goods number and their categories, the selection began to take a very long time and lays down mysql server. 
    After this we moved all products into a single table. The table structure is as [follows](http://clip2net.com/s/5OUKXm.

The table with 10 million products makes it difficult to work with mysql now. Selection from it is not quite possible, without talking about sorting. We used the sphinx, the index sphinx:

```
sql_query = SELECT \
ti.item_id, \
ti.item_id AS iid, \
crc32(ti.item_nick) AS nick, \
ti.item_title AS title, \
ti.item_sold AS sold, \
ti.item_rating AS rating, \
ti.item_popular AS popular, \
ti.item_warranty AS warranty, \
ROUND(ti.item_price*100, 0) AS price, \
ti.item_props AS props, \
COUNT(c.comment_iid) AS comments, \
GROUP_CONCAT(tcir.category_item_ref_tid) AS tids \
FROM item AS ti \
LEFT JOIN comment AS c ON ti.item_id = c.comment_iid \
INNER JOIN category_item_ref AS tcir ON ti.item_id = tcir.category_item_ref_iid \
WHERE ti.item_id >= $start AND ti.item_id <= $end \
GROUP BY ti.item_id

sql_attr_uint = sold
sql_attr_uint = rating
sql_attr_uint = comments
sql_attr_uint = warranty
sql_attr_bigint = iid
sql_attr_bigint = nick
sql_attr_bigint = price
sql_attr_bigint = popular
sql_attr_multi = uint tids from field;
```

Search through the Sphinx is faster, but there are many attributes, in particular sql_attr_multi tids that slows search and sorting. Sampling time of 600 000 goods is about 18 ~ 19 seconds. We tried to tie products only to one category (an attribute tids became sql_attr_uint). The sampling time decreased to 3 ~ 5 seconds, which is also not very good.

Could you tell me please what I'm doing wrong, it might be worth to build an index for sphinx in another way, because I think it should work faster. Perhaps, I need to build a table structure in another way, or use a different platform for databases, such as MySQL, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing problems as many other companies which met large dataset sets. You are lucky as it seems that your use-case is heavy reading but small writing as both issues together are worse :-)
It's important to understand that database system is nothing than virtualized file system allowing indexes and locks along with optimization for fast search (in data and indexes).

There is no reason why almost 10m items in table does not have to be fast using appropriate queries. But you are required to optimize system and queries. What does it mean?

You said that you want to support fast sort for goods in one category. How should I design it?

- Lets say there are 10m items, 10k categories so each has 100 items of good
- Sorting in one category by value means that there are duplicated data, both category and price, in sorted way - in the form of index including both category id and price value
- Performed query in appropriate way just use this index. First of all it searches for category which is fast because it's represented using some kind of hashtable in the form of index - speaking of which the index for 10m rows will probably be read in one fetch as e.g. MS SQL caches 512kb within on hard (drive) read. Once you find required category in the index, you took sorted 100 items so you got collection of physical row ids which needs to be found on drive. The last step is to physically read 100 database rows id their ids which can take couple ms even in randomly selected identifiers.

I wrote this section to show, that even one large database table can be fast for your queries but you need to tune the query and provide particular proper index(es).

You should try classic approach:

1. Write use cases - which are top queries I want to optimize in my system?
2. Take these queries and optimize your tables and indexes

It seems for me that it's not necessary to cut your data in more tables, you should eliminate the amount of data that queries need to search through using approach above - just use correct indexes.

You mentioned joining of tables. It can be very long operation for large data so popular system is to duplicate data and just provide one table (fastest approach) to search duplicated data from other tables. Obvious problem is update of this data as you need to atomically update two tables. Once you talked about reading only, it does not seem like a real problem for you - you can just update duplicated data when you update original one.

There is couple other approaches how to cope even with massive reading and writing. It's nice to study architecture of top internet companies like twitter or facebook and find out how they cope with similar problems.